# Water in kitchen sink smells

Tags: plumbing

Started happening about 3 weeks ago.
I have run the HOT water, put it in a glass and waited a couple of minutes: NO SMELL.
I ran the cold water and put it in a glass and waited...NO SMELL

I have a septic and well water
Husband has cleaned the pipe under kitchen sink..there was nothing there

Can you help ?
Jan

Comment: So if the hot water and the cold water have NO SMELL, what does smell?  The only other option is the drain right?  What does it smell like?

Comment: Sulfur/eggs. I've used Baking Powder and Clorox in the drain. Still smells. WHen you turn the water on you can smell it. I put the 2 gls away from each other and away from the sink. they do not smell

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the anode rod in your water heater needs to be replaced.

Possibly with an aluminum/zinc alloy rod instead of magnesium or aluminum.
This is the chepest fix.

Many claim the an all plastic water heater (e.g Rheem's Marathon) cures this problem since it doesn't have the anode rod that metal water heaters have.

Answer (score 0):

I thought one of my sinks had smelly water, but it was from the drain and only happened when the water was running.

- When it doesn't smell, run water into a pan or something so it doesn't go down the drain.  Does it smell?
- Set the pan aside and run water from the faucet normally.  Does it smell?

If only #2 smells, then it's the drain.  If it's improperly vented, then the smell may not have anything to do with the trap under the sink.  Pouring stuff down the drain won't fix gas venting.